# symfony 3 time when log in and log out

Tags: time, symfony-3.1

I'm pretty much new in symfony 3, so how I could get time when user log in and log out.. I know i should create entity for time.. that entity would have id,userID startTime, endTime.. and user should have a connection(many to many, that lot of user could have lot of log in.. ) with this entity.... I'd like to store in database this information. I tried to search on google but I found nothing in common.

I'd like to activate time startTime when this button is pressed 
     Sign
     in
and code in controller

```
   @Route("/login", name="authentication_login") 
    public function loginActionAction(Request $request)
    {
        $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();
        return $this->render('AppBundle:uzduotis:login.html.twig', array(
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error,
        ));
    }
```

then for endTime

```
/**
 * @Route("/logout", name="logout")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 */
public function logoutAction(Request $request)
{
    $session = $this->$request->getSession();
    $session = $this->get('session')->clear();
    return $this->render('AppBundle:uzduotis:login.html.twig');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this answer I assume you store the users in the database. If not, please show how you do it.

First of all please have a look at the doctrine documentation on how to connect entities to each other. In your case this should help:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

There's also a pretty good tutorial on this subject in the Symfony documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html

In the controller you can fetch the currently logged in user by executing `$user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();`. That will return the database entity of the user that you can modify immediately. E.g. by adding a new record to the time table (example code):

```
$time = new TimeLog();
$time->setUser($user);
$time->setType('login');
$time->setTimestamp(time());
```

In case saving does not work, try with the persist and flush methods of `$this->get('doctrine')->getManager()`. There's lots of documentation about this, too.